# using shift with an empty input js

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a basic question about using the .shift method.  Below is my working code to convert a number to the sum of all digits.  After converting to string and splitting to array, if the first value is the '-' sign I use .shift to remove this element, then make the next value negative.  My question is, where does the '-' go?  What happens to this value that I have not assigned to any variable?

Moving forward, should I be concerned about using this method if it will potentially leave values sort of 'floating' around in my code?

```
function sumDigits(num) {
var numArr = num.toString().split('');
if (numArr[0] === '-') {
    numArr.shift();
    numArr[0] *= -1;
}
var total = numArr.map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
return total;}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since arrays in Javascript are mutable, each element in an array is a reference to a place in memory. When you create a new array or add an element to an array, Javascript implicitly allocates memory and then creates new references from the array to point to the newly allocated objects in memory.

In your situation, when you `shift()`, you're removing the reference to the memory that contains that element, and not the element itself.

So how does Javascript actually delete these items from memory? Garbage collection. One simple mechanism of garbage collection checks all of the objects in memory and counts the number of references to it. If the number of references is 0, then it indicates to the garbage collector that the object can be deleted from memory.

So when after you delete the reference to the first element in the array with `shift()`, the garbage collector later comes in and sees that the object that the first element in the array used to point to now has nothing that references it. Thus it is safe to garbage collect, and is therefore deallocated from memory.

All in all, you do not need to worry about memory leaks from using `shift()` thanks to Javascript's garbage collection mechanism.

Here is an interesting [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) about Javascript memory management, if you're curious to learn more.